# Add condition ngFor outside loop

Tags: angular, ngfor, clearfix

I want to add a div with class clearfix but I need to add it outside the loop. Is any way to achieve that?

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 item" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
        <div class="header">
            <img src="{{item.image}}" *ngIf="!!item.image">
            <h4>{{item.title | uppercase}}</h4>
        </div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix" *ngIf="(i+1) % 4 == 0"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `template/ng-template` or `ng-container` to achieve it:

```
<div class="row">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 item" >
          <div class="header">
              <img src="{{item.image}}" *ngIf="!!item.image">
              <h4>{{item.title | uppercase}}</h4>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix" *ngIf="(i+1) % 4 == 0"></div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for